# Android - Create URI with Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to connect to Microsoft with Oauth2 to get the authentication code. The user logs in to a WebView.
Once connected, the Microsoft application redirects to `com.example.myapplication://oauth2microsoft`

I can connect but once connected, I get in my WebView: `Web page not available, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME`

In my AndroidManifes.xml, I added well:

```
<activity android:name=".oauth2Activity">
    <intent-filter>
         <data android:scheme="oauth2microsoft"/>

         <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

My Intent doesn't seem to be being taken into account. When I go to com.example.myapplication://oauth2microsoft, I am not redirected to my application.

I don't understand. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The scheme part in `com.example.myapplication://oauth2microsoft` is `com.example.myapplication`, not `oauth2microsoft`.

So you could try with:

```
<intent-filter>
     <data android:scheme="com.example.myapplication" />
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
</intent-filter>
```